# Creating a re-usable function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm extracting a part of the current button ID and want it to re-use this in several other functions.

How could I make the following section common,

```
var idRec = $(this).attr("id"),
inp = idRec.substr(4,this.id.length);
```

So that it could be used in multiple `.on('click',)` events. Please see the following code and advise,

```
$(function() {
  function studentsRecords(e) {
      //do_somehting
}

$(document).on('click', '.studentID', function(e) {
    var idRec = $(this).attr("id"),
    inp = idRec.substr(2, this.id.length);
    //do_something_using_inp
  }).on('click', '.admissionID', function(e) {
    //do_something_else_using_inp
  });
});
```

Comment: Just remove keyword `var` and add `var idRec, inp;` before `$(document).on('click'`

Comment: two times on click like you're having is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    function studentsRecords(e) {
        //do_somehting
    }

    function get_id(that){
      var idRec = that.id;
      var inp = idRec.substr(2,that.id.length);
      return inp
    } 


    $(document)
        .on('click', '.studentID', function(e) {

             var inp = get_id(this);
            //do_something_using_inp
        })
        .on('click', '.admissionID', function(e) {
             var inp = get_id(this);
            //do_something_else_using_inp
        })
})
```

Comment: @levi - And also `$(that).attr("id")` can be reduced to simply `that.id` :) and don't forget to change `this.id.length` to `that.id.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare **inp** before **click function**. http://fiddle.jshell.net/x3xo25vz/